# Laravel 5.6 Ajax Post 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.6

Hello i am sending large string data via Ajax Post Request and its working fine on localhost but not working on live server i am sending some image data then this image data is converted to images on server..also its taking so much time to send this data average data size is between 4 to 7 MB..also can you suggest a better way  so it can be done quickly..also things are setup properly i am including CSRF token and URL is also good but don't know why this error is occurring

**Error => Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error**

**My controller code where i am sending request**

```
$pid    =  $request->input('id');
        $pt_id  =  $request->input('pt_id');
        $pname  =  $request->input('name');
        $isBack =  $request->input('isBack');
        $qty    =  $request->input('qty');
        $paper  =  $request->input('paper');
        $previewFront  =  $request->input('previewFront');
        $previewBack   =  $request->input('previewBack');
        $PrintDataFront  =  $request->input('PrintDataFront');
        $PrintDataBack   =  $request->input('PrintDataBack');
        $cart_item_id = uniqid();
        //Store Img Data
        $pf = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $previewFront);
        $pf = str_replace(' ', '+', $pf);
        $pf_n = $cart_item_id.'_f_.'.'png';
        \File::put(public_path(). '/cart_preview/' . $pf_n, base64_decode($pf));
        $pb = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $previewBack);
        $pb = str_replace(' ', '+', $pb);
        $pb_n = $cart_item_id.'_b_.'.'png';
        \File::put(public_path(). '/cart_preview/' . $pb_n, base64_decode($pb));
        $pdf = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $PrintDataFront);
        $pdf = str_replace(' ', '+', $pdf);
        $pdf_n = $cart_item_id.'_f_.'.'png';
        \File::put(public_path(). '/orders/' . $pdf_n, base64_decode($pdf));
        $pdb = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $PrintDataBack);
        $pdb = str_replace(' ', '+', $pdb);
        $pdb_n = $cart_item_id.'_b_.'.'png';
        \File::put(public_path(). '/orders/' . $pdb_n, base64_decode($pdb));
        //Get Prices and qty
        $opriceitem = PriceTableItem::find($qty);
        $itemQty = $opriceitem->qty;
        $basePrice = $opriceitem->total;
        if($isBack == 'true') {
            $backPrice =  $opriceitem->total_back;
            $itemPrice = $opriceitem->total + $opriceitem->total_back;
            $pricePerPiece = $opriceitem->item_price + $opriceitem->item_price_back;            
        }else {
            $backPrice =  'INCLUDED';
            $itemPrice = $opriceitem->total; 
            $pricePerPiece = $opriceitem->item_price; 
        }
        if($paper == 'Premium White') {
            $paperPrice = ($itemPrice/100) *60;
            $itemPrice = $itemPrice + ($itemPrice/100) *60;
        } else {
            $paperPrice = 'INCLUDED';
        }
        //Get all Available Qty
        $allQty = PriceTableItem::where('tid', $pt_id)->get();
        $allAvailableQty = array();
        foreach($allQty as $allqtyarry) {array_push($allAvailableQty, $allqtyarry->qty);}       
        //Create Cart Object
        $item = [
            "id"      => $cart_item_id,
            "pid"      => $pid,
            "name"    => $pname,
            "qty"     => $itemQty,
            "price_table_id"    => $pt_id,
            "paperType"  => $paper,
            "backCharges"  => $backPrice,
            "paperCharges"  => $paperPrice,
            "isBack" => $isBack,
            "pricePerPiece"    => $pricePerPiece,
            "basePrice"    => $basePrice,
            "totalPrice"    => $itemPrice,
            "allQty"    => $allAvailableQty,
        ];
        $request->session()->put('cart.items.' . $cart_item_id, $item);
        return 'Success';
```

Comment: Are there images on your server?

Comment: no there is no image saved on server

Comment: please think of this. PHP is server side code. In your code, you are getting .png files. right?

Comment: i know php is server side code..it working fine on localhost but not on live server

Comment: On live server, there isn't any images. If you want , you should upload images. PHP code can not get anything from local PC.

Comment: no on my php code i am sending Data URI from Canvas then this data is converted  to image and saved on server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176456/discussion-between-sunil-meena-and-shildra).

Comment: Are you getting only error 500 and nothing else? If so, enable debug so you can get better description of the error. Make sure your php.ini file is set up properly and also permissions are fine for your server folders (I always get problems with the storage folder).

Comment: @adolfotcar  thank you so much... i forgot to set debug mode to true error is because of there is no directory in storage folder where image is saved..thank again have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote
>   Are you getting only error 500 and nothing else? If so, enable debug so you can get better description of the error. Make sure your php.ini file is set up properly and also permissions are fine for your server folders (I always get problems with the storage folder).